# Creating Jenkins pipeline using a multi-project gradle build

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a multi-project Gradle build working locally.
There is a parent gradle file, build.gradle
The settings.gradle file assigns the projects to their respective gradle build files:

```
include 'load'
include 'loadRemote' 

project(':loadRemote').buildFileName = 'remoteLoad_build.gradle'
project(':load').buildFileName = 'load_build.gradle' 

rootProject.name = 'EquipLoad'
```

The build.gradle parent file calls a `buildAll` command to build the 2 projects from the command line locally.
I created a Jenkins file to build both projects. But the Jenkins pipeline does not recognize the specific project tasks.
These are the tasks for the `buildAll` command
gradle.projectsEvaluated {

```
    task compileAll (dependsOn: [project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage]) {
         compileAll.finalizedBy project(':load').loadCleanCompileStage
    }

    task packageAll (dependsOn: [project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadPackage]) {
        packageAll.finalizedBy project(':load').loadPackage
    }

    task buildAll (dependsOn: [compileAll]) {
        buildAll.finalizedBy packageAll
    }
}
```

The error in Jenkins is that it does not recognize the task `project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage`

How can I identify a multi-build project in Jenkins?
Do I have to add the settings.gradle file?

**UPDATE**
I thought that the different build files could not be located in the project so I added this to the settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'EquipLoad'

include 'load'
project(':load').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, rootProject.rootDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/Load")
project(':load').buildFileName = 'load_build.gradle'

include 'loadRemote' 
project(':loadRemote').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, rootProject.rootDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/LoadRemote")
project(':loadRemote').buildFileName = 'remoteLoad_build.gradle'
```

The error is still the same, the build.gradle file (parent) does not recognize the dependency task `project(':loadRemote').remoteLoadCleanCompileStage`
Looking at the debug statements, the child build gradle files are found and identified: 
Evaluating project ':loadRemote' using build file '/var/.../loadRemote/remoteLoad_build.gradle'.
The same text is shown for the load build file.
Yet the tasks within these gradle build files are not recognized in the parent build.gradle file.

Comment: I know this was months ago ... but could you post your jenkins pipeline file?  I'd like to see how you configured the scm portion of the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a simple case sensitive mistake.
I named the folders: Load and LoadRemote. But identified them in the gradle scripts as ':load' and ':loadRemote'.  By changing the script text to ':Load' and ':LoadRemote' fixed my problem.